# Compiling problem when using minted

Tags: miktex, minted, windows

I want to highlight Python code in a Latex document and I tried to reproduce this [example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Code_Highlighting_with_minted), but I get several errors, I cannot even put all of them here as they are a lot...

An example is:

```
graphics\mathcolor.ltx:20: Missing $ inserted
graphics\mathcolor.ltx:20: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
graphics\mathcolor.ltx:23: LaTeX Error: \mathcolor allowed only in math mode.
graphics\mathcolor.ltx:24: Undefined control sequence
...
xcolor\xcolor-2022-06-12.sty:802: Missing $ inserted
```

I have no idea where the problem is.
The only thing I can say is I had to install manually the packages because the laptop I am using is the one from work and I can't use MikTex console to install them.

I am in Windows environment and I am using PyCharm as editor. I also set `-shell-escape` as argument.

Does anyone have any suggestion?

**Update**

This is the output when I try to compile the document:

```
pdflatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -output-format=pdf "-output-directory=C:/Users/cicciodevoto/Work/Coursework2/Report/out" "-aux-directory=C:/Users/cicciodevoto/Work/Coursework2/Report/auxil" -shell-escape test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\minted\minted.sty
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval
.sty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"))))
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fvextra\fvextra.sty
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyvrb.sty)
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\upquote\upquote.sty)
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\lineno\lineno.sty

Package lineno Warning: `amsmath' must be loaded before `lineno' for patches to be applied.

)) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\shellesc.sty")
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\ifplatform\ifplatform.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\catchfile.sty"))
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.tex))
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\framed\framed.sty) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\float\float.sty"))
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor-2022-06-12.sty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\pdftex.def")
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:19: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:20: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:20: Missing $ inserted

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:20: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:20: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:21: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:21: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:23: Undefined control sequence

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:23: LaTeX Error: \mathcolor allowed only in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:24: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:24: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:25: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:25: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Illegal parameter number in definition of \@@mod
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Undefined control sequence

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `##1'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Illegal parameter number in definition of \XC@@tmp
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Missing number, treated as zero
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Missing } inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Undefined control sequence

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `##1'.

See the xcolor package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:26: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:27: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:28: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:29: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:30: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:30: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:32: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:34: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:35: Undefined control sequence

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 35.


LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 37.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:37: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:37: Missing { inserted

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 38.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:38: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:38: Missing { inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:39: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:40: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:42: Undefined control sequence

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 42.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:44: Limit controls must follow a math operator
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:44: Limit controls must follow a math operator
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:45: Limit controls must follow a math operator
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:45: Limit controls must follow a math operator
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:46: Limit controls must follow a math operator
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:46: Limit controls must follow a math operator
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:49: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:50: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:50: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:53: Undefined control sequence

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 53.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:55: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:56: Missing { inserted

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 56.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:56: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:56: Missing { inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:57: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:57: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:58: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:60: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:62: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:62: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:64: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:65: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:66: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:67: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:68: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:68: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:68: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:70: You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 70.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:70: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:70: Missing { inserted

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 70.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:70: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:70: Missing { inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:71: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:71: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:73: Undefined control sequence

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 73.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:73: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:73: Missing { inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:74: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:74: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:75: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:77: Undefined control sequence

LaTeX Warning: Command \l invalid in math mode on input line 77.


LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 77.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:77: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:77: Missing { inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:79: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:80: Undefined control sequence

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 80.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:80: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:80: Missing { inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:81: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:83: Undefined control sequence
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:84: Undefined control sequence

LaTeX Warning: Command \c invalid in math mode on input line 84.

C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:84: Missing $ inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:84: Missing { inserted
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:85: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:86: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:87: Extra }, or forgotten $
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\mathcolor.ltx:88: Undefined control sequence
)
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor-2022-06-12.sty:802: Missing $ inserted
(That makes 100 errors; please try again.)
C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor-2022-06-12.sty:802:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on "C:/Users\cicciodevoto\Work\Coursework2\Report\auxil\test.log".

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This is the latex document, which it's exactly the same as the link:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
import numpy as np
    
def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
    
    #compute the bitwise xor matrix
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 

    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(i+1, m):
            [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
            for k in range(len(r)):
                VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                
                if M is None:
                    M = np.copy(VT)
                else:
                    M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)
                
                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)
    
    return M
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

**Update 2**

These are the first 160 lines of the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (MiKTeX 2.9.6600 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.9.8)  2 JAN 2024 15:49
entering extended mode
**./test.tex
(test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.17> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\minted\minted.s
ty
Package: minted 2023/12/18 v2.9 Yet another Pygments shim for LaTeX

(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval
.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty"
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetkeys.sty"
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fvextra\fvextra
.sty
Package: fvextra 2023/11/28 v1.6.1 fvextra - extensions and patches for fancyvr
b

(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolb
ox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count87
)
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fancyvrb\fancyv
rb.sty
Package: fancyvrb 2023/11/06 4.5b verbatim text (tvz,hv)
\FV@CodeLineNo=\count88
\FV@InFile=\read1
\FV@TabBox=\box26
\c@FancyVerbLine=\count89
\FV@StepNumber=\count90
\FV@OutFile=\write3
)
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\upquote\upquote
.sty
Package: upquote 2012/04/19 v1.3 upright-quote and grave-accent glyphs in verba
tim
)
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\lineno\lineno.s
ty
Package: lineno 2023/05/20 line numbers on paragraphs v5.3
\linenopenalty=\count91
\output=\toks15
\linenoprevgraf=\count92
\linenumbersep=\dimen103
\linenumberwidth=\dimen104
\c@linenumber=\count93
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count94
\c@LN@truepage=\count95
\c@internallinenumber=\count96
\c@internallinenumbers=\count97
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen105
\bframerule=\dimen106
\bframesep=\dimen107
\bframebox=\box27


Package lineno Warning: `amsmath' must be loaded before `lineno' for patches to
 be applied.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3180.
)
\c@FancyVerbWriteLine=\count98
\c@FancyVerbBufferIndex=\count99
\c@FancyVerbBufferLength=\count100
\c@FancyVerbBufferLine=\count101
\c@FV@oldbufferlength=\count102
\c@FV@TrueTabGroupLevel=\count103
\c@FV@TrueTabCounter=\count104
\FV@TabBox@Group=\box28
\FV@TmpLength=\skip43
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStart=\count105
\c@FV@HighlightLinesStop=\count106
\FV@LoopCount=\count107
\FV@NCharsBox=\box29
\FV@BreakIndent=\dimen108
\FV@BreakIndentNChars=\count108
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeft=\dimen109
\FV@BreakSymbolSepLeftNChars=\count109
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRight=\dimen110
\FV@BreakSymbolSepRightNChars=\count110
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft=\dimen111
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeftNChars=\count111
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRight=\dimen112
\FV@BreakSymbolIndentRightNChars=\count112
\c@FancyVerbLineBreakLast=\count113
\FV@LineBox=\box30
\FV@LineIndentBox=\box31
\c@FV@BreakBufferDepth=\count114
\FV@LineWidth=\dimen113
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\ifthen.sty"
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\shellesc.sty"
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Unrestricted shell escape enabled on input line 67.
)
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\ifplatform\ifpl
atform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/21 v0.26 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\catchfile.sty"
Package: catchfile 2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)
))
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.sty
(C:\Users\cicciodevoto\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xstring\xstring.tex
```

Comment: please show a small conplete example. Your error is about `\mathcolor` which does not occur in the page you reference.

Comment: I added the latex document and the full list of error I obtained.

Comment: see https://github.com/latex-lineno/lineno/issues/5

Comment: Can you show your .log file so we can see which package version you have?

Comment: The log file is too big, I can't add it to the original question. Do I put it in an "answer"?

Comment: Can you show the first 100 or so lines?

Comment: It seems strange that some package seem rather new, while others are several years outdated. They are also take from two different paths.

Comment: Maybe try the usual miktex advise: update both in user and admin mode?

Comment: I can't update in admin mode as this is my work laptop and I don't have the rights to do it.

Comment: @cicciodevoto sorry, I can't help you further, I'm not a miktex user.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz don't worry, that's fine :-)